# Itô’s formula and Wiener process

Tags: itos-lemma, wiener

The Wikipedia page on the formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma and some textbooks I  have looked at say we must assume that the relevant time-dependent function is over an Itô drift-diffusion process, and that the diffusion process is a Wiener process https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process.

Is it absolutely essential that the process be a Wiener process?

Regards and New Year best wishes.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question completely but you can apply Itô's Lemma to any semimartingale (a sum of a local martingale and a bounded variation process), see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma#Non-continuous_semimartingales. Amongst others, these include non-continuous processes which jump. All Itô processes are semimartingales, so are e.g. Lévy processes.

Comment: Thanks. The definition of a Wiener process requires being independent and Gaussian. Is a non-continuous process which jumps also Gaussian?

Comment: Look at Levy processes for example. They are a straight forward generalisation of the Wiener process and really only rely on independent increments. They can jump infinitely often and still you can apply Ito's Lemma to them.

Comment: Thanks, but the question is whether a non-continuous process which jumps is *Gaussian*, i.e. drawn from the normal distribution.

Comment: Looking at the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process it suggests that all Gaussian processes are Wiener processes, but not all Wiener processes are Gaussian.

Comment: Where does it say this? A Wiener process (aka Brownian motion) is a special case of a Gaussian Process. A Wiener process is a Gaussian process, an Ito process and a Levy process. But not every Gaussian process is a Wiener process?! Look at a Brownian bridge which has dependent increments. Thus, it is certainly not a Wiener process. It's not a Levy process either. But it is a semimartingale and hence you can apply Ito's Lemma to a Brownian bridge.

Comment: Sorry, long day. I meant, every Gaussian process is a *Levy* process, but is every Levy process a Gaussian process?

Comment: No neither. A Brownian motion is a Gaussian process and a Lévy process. A Brownian bridge is a Gaussian process which is not a Lévy process. A Poisson process is a Lévy process which is not a Gaussian process. The Heston Stochastic volatility model is neither Gaussian nor Levy. So, neither Lévy and Gaussian are contained in the other one.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102754/discussion-between-buckner-and-keschn).